# Merge Multiple Worksheets into a Single Worksheet in the Same Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have code for each sheet I want to move but I am wondering if there was a way to reduce this code.

This is what I currently use to  move each sheet times 8 or so sheets:

```
   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "ONI" Then
        Set RNG1 = ONI.Range("A1:AK1").EntireColumn
        Set RNG2 = All.Range("A1:AK1").EntireColumn
        RNG2.Value = RNG1.Value
    End If
Next
```

This is the code I use when I want to move a single column from all sheets to a single sheet. I can't figure out how to modify it to include more columns.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "MainSheet" Then
        Set RNG1 = ws.Range("A1:A700")
        Set RNG2 = Sheets ("MainSheet") _ 
        .Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        RNG2.Value = RNG1.Value
    End If
Next
```

So basically is it possible to modify this code to include multiple columns?

Comment: What is `All` in your first code snippet?

Comment: Do you really want `A1:A700` every time or do you just want `A1`  down to the last row?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I  just want say "A1:L300" from all sheets to "A1:L300" to the MainSheet.

Answer (score 1):

Kudos for going for the **value transfer** instead of **copy/paste**. You just need to resize your `Rng2` to match the size of `Rng1`.

I also modified this to work with dynamic row counts. If you need to copy a static range for each sheet, you can get rid of the `LR` bits and hard code the range. You need to keep `nLR` as this determines the next available row on your main sheet.

```
Sub Test()

Dim ms As Worksheet: Set ms = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainSheet")
Dim ws As Worksheet, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
Dim LR As Long, nLR As Long   '(LR = Last Row, nLR = New Last Row for Main Sheet)

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> ms.Name Then

        'Determine Relavent Ranges (last rows)
        LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        nLR = ms.Range("A" & ms.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

        'Set the ranges
        Set Rng1 = ws.Range("A1:L" & LR)
        Set Rng2 = ms.Range("A" & nLR).Resize(Rng1.Rows.Count, Rng1.Columns.Count)

        'Value Transfer
        Rng2.Value = Rng1.Value

    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Now I see it! Thanks for the help. You are right, I have been trying to move away from copy and paste and it has been so much better in terms of speed.

Answer (score -1):

Think you need a nested loop here, long time since i wrote vba so i give pseudo code, hope this help you on the way.

```
for each ws
dim rang as Range
for Each rnge In Range("A1:H1").Columns
do something
next
next
```